# Why not only use asynchronous messages between microservices

Tags: multithreading, web-services, http, asynchronous, apache-kafka

Why dont we just use async messages/events as the only mode of communication in a microservices architecture, and remove all the sync/http calls?
I am not able to imagine how sync can have advantage over async in any situation whatsoever.

Imagine the following call chain among 3 services A, B, C:
UI -> A -> B -> C

- UI makes a call to A requesting for some data.
- A needs to call B to get some data on which it will do some processing before returning to UI.
- Similarly, B needs to call C to get some data.

Imagine that all the services have (finite) thread pools to service incoming requests.
The thread in A which has accepted the connection request from UI will make a HTTP request to B.
Since the request to B is a form of IO, this thread will be preempted until data travels from from A->B->C->B->A, thus wasting the thread for a long time.
Similar thread preemptions will occur in the rest of the services as well.

---

If we had a message-driven design, we can have the following thread pools in every service:

- One thread pool which is just running kafka consumers to read response from downstream service.
- One thread pool for accepting new request from upstream service.

Consider the following sequence of events:

- A::Thread1 gets request from UI, and produces message '*MsgAB*' encapsulating the request id along with the core data to the message queue.
- A::Thread1 will insert the request connection object to a global mapping of `requestId -> requestObject`.
- A::Thread1 is now free to service more requests.
- Similarly, B would produce msg for C.
- C would create a response message to be read by B, which in turn will produce *MsgBA*.
- Now A::Thread2 running one of the kafka consumers would consume *MsgBA* encapsulating the original request id.
- A::Thread2 will reply back to the UI using the request object from the global map.

The advantage of this design is that the threads are free instantly increasing the throughput of the service, apart from the usual benefits of message-driven architecture like scalability and extensibility (messages can be also read by logging, tracking, data-analysis or any other services without the producing service even knowing about it).

To handle timeouts, we can adopt the following strategy:

- We can keep all the request ID's in any time-sensitive data structure which allows quick access and removal of the oldest entry.
  Heap or LRU cache (using the standard DLL + hashmap implementation) can be good options for this data structure.
- We can have a dedicated thread running a scheduler which goes through this data structure and replies back a timeout error to all the expired/timed-out requests.

So why are HTTP-based microservice architectures so prevalent?

Comment: I think message-driven between services and http for external clients (only) is a very valid way to do it. I don’t know what the answer can be except that a lot of people tend to adopt new tech in a superficial way.

Comment: It seems to me that something like node.js-based web service is basically that, except instead of a kafka thread pool it has an http thread pool.

Comment: Regarding HTTP vs another protocol e.g. Kafka: it's possible that part of it is the well-known structure of HTTP and the sheer amount of support and tools available for HTTP.

Comment: Good point @root

Comment: several reasons - cost (extra brokers, disk space), latency (extra round trip to broker, more if you want durability), performance (kafka networking code is BAD, from personal experience. please write a benchmark and see how may msgs/sec you can produce from a single client to a single broker, and what the latency distribution will be)

Comment: So I guess the answer is performance and complexity. Any of you want to write a formal answer?